# Keeping vectors in an array that obey a true statement

Tags: matlab

Basically I'm generating various positions. I want to keep the positions in an array where a statement is true. I'm a complete novice at MATLAB, so please excuse the novice question. I spent quite a while searching for an answer to this question, so now I'm turning to the board for help. :/

For example...Here I want to keep all rows that obey "Outside".

```
Outside = [];
Position = [1 1 1; 1 2 2; 3 3 3; 3 4 4];
sq_dist = sum(Position.^2);
Outside = sq_dist>12;
```

I had tried a for loop:

```
for outside = 1
Outside = [];
Position = [1 1 1; 1 2 2; 3 3 3; 3 4 4];
sq_dist = sum(Position.^2);
Outside = sq_dist>12;
end
```

But it didn't seem to work. All it did was generate the corresponding positions that obeyed the statement. (So a series of 1s and 0s). I also tried:

```
Outside = [];
Position = [1 1 1; 1 2 2; 3 3 3; 3 4 4];
sq_dist = sum(Position.^2);
Outside = sq_dist>12;
Position = Position(Outside == 1)
```

But the above only gives me the fist column, and I need the entire row.

Would anyone mind helping me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple conditions you can do the following:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8];
v1 = v(v>5); %keep values greater than 5
```

In your case, you can find the squared distance as follows

```
sqr_pos = sum(position.^2, 2);
```

because sum will return the sum of the columns, so you have to tell it to sum along the rows.

Then you can find what is outside your sphere as follows

```
positions_outside = position(sqr_pos > 12, :);
```

where `:` means all the columns `(x, y, z)`

Edit:
You can do it in one line:

```
position_outside = position(sum(position.^2, 2)>12, :);
```